# How to click on angular dropdown menu in Selenium

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use python selenium to automate some report generating on a website, however I am struggling to identify the element I need to click on the page due to the javascript. In firefox there is a DOM Event icon when I inspect the element. I have tried alot of variations including xpath etc but no luck.

```
<account-groups ng-if="EventsList.ToggleService.accountGroup();">
<button class="btn-default" ng-disabled="AccountGroupsCtrl.isDisabled()" ng-click="AccountGroupsCtrl.toggleFlyout()">
</button>
</account-groups>
```

**EDIT** For anyone viewing this the issue was because I had not switched frames using driver.switch_to.frame('frame_name'). Once this step is carried out the rest of the solutions below worked in identifying the elements. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have shared it is not clear if the *WebElement* is a *Dropdown*. However as the desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element to invoke `click()` on the element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn-default[ng-click^='AccountGroupsCtrl']"))).click()
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn-default' and starts-with(@ng-click,'AccountGroupsCtrl')]"))).click()
  ```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: @NikBro You need to update the question with the exact _Manual Steps_ you are trying to _Automate_ along with the reveant _HTML_, your _code trials_ and the _error stack trace_ (if any).

Answer (score -2):

You can use following code for selecting from dropdown.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('*****'))
select.select_by_visible_text('****')
```

Comment: This is for the basic HTML select types , where as this is angular (ng-select) type.